# Svn update script skips the svn

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script that will execute a svn update on the root but I don't understand the results I'm getting. Here is the code executed by my script:

```
$update = "svn --username user --password pwd update svn://URL";
$res = exec($update);
echo $res;
```

However, the echo of the `$res` gives me " Skipped 'svn://URL' ".

I've used a similar method to do a svn checkout and it worked fine. Is there something I'm missing to be able to do the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're inside a Working copy.  If the script runs in a non-SVN directory, you'll get this error:

```
  Skipped '/non/workingcopy/path'
```

Comment: Okay I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Currently, my script is executed at the root of my server, the same way I executed the svn checkout script.

Comment: @OlivierParenteau in your script, before you try to run the svn update, just run this just to confirm where the script is where you thinks it is executing from `echo __DIR__;`  Then on the command line, take the directory, and try this `svn info <directorypath>` and see if you get the working copy details.

Comment: I tried that and I do get the working copy details. I thought I might have been using the wrong URL for the svn but using the path, url or repository root displayed in those informations doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your script is running outside the working copy. Anyway... if you are developing under *NIX environment, you can also try this approach:

```
$result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/svn update /path/to/project --username user --password pass");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use this method. Thanks.